# Regex: if string ends with numerical values - drop it, OR if string ends with single letter - drop it, OR leave it

Tags: python, regex

Here is a sample of a dataset I have:

| ID | Project |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 21st Townhouse 318 |
| 2 | The Residences 6 |
| 3 | Villanova Tower B |
| 4 | The Hills H |
| 5 | City Park |

I need to transform 'Project' column so that:

1. if a row ends with numeric values, they should be dropped
2. if a row ends with single letter, it should be dropped
3. else, leave as it is

Here is how I want it to look like:

| ID | Project |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 21st Townhouse |
| 2 | The Residences |
| 3 | Villanova Tower |
| 4 | The Hills |
| 5 | City Park |

I tried to search for some solution, and found this(for first condition with numeric values only):

```
df['Project']=df.Project[~((df.Project.astype(str).str.match("(.*\d)")) & (df.Project.astype(str).str.len() > 1))]
```

It worked, however, I tried to apply it for the second condition as well:

```
df['Project']=df.Project[~((df.Project.astype(str).str.match("(.*\w)")) & (df.Project.astype(str).str.len() == 1))]
```

But, It failed

Can you help me, please?
Thank you!

Comment: The regexp `\b(?:\d+|\w)$` will match a number or single letter at the end.

Comment: Your regular expressions are both missing `$`, so they match anywhere in the string.

Comment: It didn't work for me, can you please write a whole code, maybe I applied your regexp incorrectly. Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you need `replace`: `df['Project']=df['Project'].str.replace(r'\s+(?:\d+|[A-Za-z])$', '', regex=True)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Worked, thank you so much!

Comment: This seems like the kind of task that is overkill for a regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['Project']=df['Project'].str.replace(r'\s+(?:\d+|[A-Za-z])$', '', regex=True)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lna81W/1).

*Details*:

- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?:\d+|[A-Za-z])` - a non-capturing group matching either

  - `\d+` - one or more digits
  - `|` - or
  - `[A-Za-z]` - an ASCII letter (use `[^\W\d_]` to match any Unicode letter)
- `$` - end of string.

If your strings have no whitespace before the last number/letter, you may use

```py
df['Project'].str.replace(r'\b(?:\d+|[A-Za-z])$', '', regex=True).str.rstrip()
```

The `\b` matches a word boundary making sure there is no letter, digit or `_` right before the final digits/letter, and `.str.rstrip()` will strip the trailing whitespace.

Comment: It worked! thanks))